# Port AOSP to i9300

Tags: android, build, android-source

I want to port pure AOSP to my GT-I9300 (Samsung Galaxy S3). I am new to all this.
I know that I will have to setup the environment for building AOSP. I have the environment and all the prerequisite as mentioned in http://source.android.com/source/building.html.

Now all i am worried about for system drivers for I9300.

i found nexus binaries from google but i was unable to find any such binaries for I9300.

any help will be greatly appreciated. A full tutorial please if any one can

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For Galaxy SIII Kernel and Platform you should look here,

http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=search&searchValue=GT-I9300
and download according to Version. Do look for updates.

After you have downloaded the zip, go for extraction.
The Readme with two folders Kernel and Platform will be present.